# Mailjet: Exlude an email from being tracked when open-tracking is enabled

Tags: tracking, mailjet

I am using Mailjet to send emails and have the 'open tracking' enabled ("Once activated, an invisible tracking pixel (image) is added to each email you send via Mailjet").

What I want to do is to deactivate the inclusion of this tracking pixel for certain emails. I know that it is possible with Mailjet for links to do that, but were not able to find a similar functionality for the tracking pixel.

Thank you!

Comment: Curious about if this is supported

Comment: @Frenchcooc it is (now, in any case).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. (perhaps not at the time of the original question)

API `send` request accepts the `Mj-trackopen` field.

SMTP way accepts the header `X-Mailjet-TrackOpen`

API info - https://dev.mailjet.com/email/reference/send-emails/

SMTP info - https://dev.mailjet.com/smtp-relay/custom-headers/